# Delete Attachments from a EmailMessage with Exchange Web Services

Tags: c#, email, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have the following problem. I would like to delete attachments from emails. As long as it's a normal email with attachments, that's no problem. But if the e-mail is now in an e-mail, then I can not delete the attachments. I always get the message "at least one attachment could not be deleted".

Does somebody has any idea? I am working with version 2 of Exchange Web Services.

```
       private void workEmail(EmailMessage rootMailMessage, EmailMessage subMailMessage, string filePath, int index)
    {

        EmailMessage eMessageToWork = null;
        if (subMailMessage == null)
        {
            eMessageToWork = rootMailMessage;
        }
        else
        {
            eMessageToWork = subMailMessage;
        }

        for (int i = eMessageToWork.Attachments.Count; i-- > 0; )
        {
            Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Attachment rootAttachment = eMessageToWork.Attachments[i];

            if (rootAttachment is FileAttachment)
            {
                // For now, just .odt files are not supported and it throws an exception if theres any unsupported fileextension
                checkFileTypeSupported(rootAttachment.Name);

                string strType = Path.GetExtension(rootAttachment.Name);

                // check if it is any type of supported image or pdf file
                if (checkForImageOrPdfAttachment(strType))
                {
                    // just save the image to temp folder
                    string subAttRootFileName = saveImageFileAttachment(rootAttachment, index, filePath);

                    // remove attachment
                    eMessageToWork.Attachments.Remove(rootAttachment);
                    // save the updated mail
                    rootMailMessage.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);
                }

                continue;
            }
            else // Attachment is an item attachment.
            {
                // convert attachment to itemattachment
                ItemAttachment itmAttach = rootAttachment as ItemAttachment;

                // save this item-attachment
                // Load Item with additionalProperties of MimeContent
                itmAttach.Load(EmailMessageSchema.MimeContent);

                // convert the itemattachment to a emailmessage
                EmailMessage ebMessage = itmAttach.Item as EmailMessage;

                // recursive call for possible attachments in this emailmessage
                this.workEmail(rootMailMessage, ebMessage, filePath, index + 1);

                // remove the attached mailitem from parent mail
                rootMailMessage.Attachments.Remove(rootAttachment);
                // update parent mail
                rootMailMessage.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(service, Id, new PropertySet(ItemSchema.Attachments));

    foreach (Attachment attachment in message.Attachments)
    {
            message.Attachments.Remove(attachment);
            break;
    }
    message.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This only works if I have 1 attachment. But I want to remove all attachments of all emails. The function must be callable recursively. If I now want to delete the attachments of a subemail, then I have a problem with the binding. The ItemId is always null.

Comment: I forgot something else. I want to delete all attachments except emails that are attached. In this case, I would have to search them for attachments again.